# What causes React Project to not stop with Ctrl Cwith npm stop script

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm, terminal

I had started the project via npm create react app.  Last night I  couldn't stop the react project with Ctrl C. I tried many solutions that others have pointed out like reinstalling npm and node.  I tried taskkill -F -IM node, $ ps -e|grep node to find the process to kill it but id didn't work.  I finally downloaded an extension called code runner to stop the react project and it worked.  Then now when I try the ctrl C on terminal its able to stop the react project. I want to know what was causing it and how this code runner is fixing this issue.  Also even though Ctrl C is able to stop the process it does not offer me the Y/N after pressing Ctrl Clear which is weird.

FYI I currently have to do sudo when I type npm commands.  I also never understood fully why I had to do that.  I just know its something wrong with the path of where npm was installed.  Whenever problems arise with npm or bash commands I just look up for a band-aid solution by typing some command that somebody mentioned on some forum, then just go back to doing what I was doing without really knowing how and where these installed packages are causing issues.  Can you guys offer some resources where I can better understand the overall pictures of what all these bash commands do to solve issues when problems arise?

Answer (score -1):

Kind of late, but if anyone else runs into this problem in the future:

on a mac terminal I "exit" from it and then was able to "control c" after that